# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app', not able to host on aserver

Tags: python, flask, import, python-import, web-hosting

**I am running a flask project and trying to host it**

ive removed my `__init__.py` file and added everything from my `routes.py` to my routes file to my `app.py` file. Its able to run locally on my computer but when i try to host it on railway(hosting service) it says `no module named app`

`routes.py` and `__init__.py` is empty

my file directory

[image: my file directory]

```
app.py

from flask import Flask, request, abort


app = Flask(__name__)

from flask import render_template
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go


@app.route('/')
def index()
```

```
run.py


from application import app
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=os.getenv("PORT", default=5000))
```

Answer (score 0):

At your hosting service, python paths may not have been configured.
You can have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-from-different-directory/) for a quick try to work around the problem.

In there, you may be particularly looking for
`import sys` and `sys.path.insert()` and use a relative path perhaps.

You may wish to check the current path entries with `print(sys.path)`.

Comment: But `app`  works fine on my local machine, it is just not working when i try to host it. How would 'sys' tell me where to fix my application, when it is perfectly working on my local machine?